Linear Regression producing incorrect results
I tried implementing my own linear regression algorithm using csv module. I know about pandas but I prefer to use csv module. However, the straight line is not visible. Here's my code:
from matplotlib import pyplot
import csv

m = 0
b = 0

f = open("h.csv")
reader = list(csv.reader(f))[1::]
xList = [float(i[0]) for i in reader]
yList = [float(j[1]) for j in reader]


def gradient():
    global m
    global b
    global reader

    for i in range(len(reader)):
        x = float(reader[i][0])
        y = float(reader[i][1])

        guess = m * x + b
        error = y - guess

        m += (-2 * x * error) * 0.00001
        b += (-2 * error) * 0.00001

for i in range(10000):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print(m, b)
    gradient()

pyplot.scatter(xList, yList, color = "green")
pyplot.plot(xList, [m * float(i[0]) + b for i in reader], color = "red")
print(m, b)

f.close()

I tried increasing the learning rate, decreasing it, but issue persists. Here's the output.



Try to debug the loop, see whether x and y contain proper values. :)

Linear regression has a closed-form solution if you want to minimize L1,L2 losses. If you want to do gradient descent, then what exactly are you minimizing? You can get negative errors from y - guess, that is suspicious? Should likely be (y - guess)**2 based on your derivates for m,b w.r.t this error. Also you might want to use batch size larger than 1 to compute the error - i.e. use an average of the error across more x,y pairs in updating your parameters.

I do not understand why this question has been voted down. If there is anything I need to change in my question, I will be happy to know.
